# Does UNIX V7 have a built-in file editor?

Tags: unix

I can use `cat` to display the content of a file in UNIX V7, but I don't know how can I edit the content of a file.

Is there a built-in file editor in UNIX V7?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The original editors are [**ed(1)**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ed) (line-oriented text editor) and [**sed(1)**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed) (stream-oriented text editor). These editors were available from the very beginning.

Comment: Does UNIX V7 also have a built-in hex viewer?

Comment: Use [`od -x`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/od)

Comment: sed(1) was new in Unix v7; it was not present in v5 or v6.  ed(1) has been there since v1 though, and was in PDP-7 Unix as well, so it definitely qualifies as being there from the very beginning.